# Kml not overlaying onto Google Map

Tags: javascript, kml, google-maps-api, overlay, visual-studio

I created a basic dashboard with MVC 4, visual studio 2012, The dashboard displays a Google map. Here is an image of the dashboard:
[image]

My intention is to be able to take this Kml file:
[image]

And successfully overlay it, onto the Google map, on the dashboard.

I have heard about the 'Geomxl3', the Kml map parser, below is my layout of how i used the Geoxml3:
[image]

However, it built without a problem and the dashboard opened up without a problem, but, there was no kml to be seen,the kml had not been overlayed. Is there a mistake in my script? am i not using the correct method of overlaying kml files onto a a Google map? must i use the Xml schema of my Kml file instead of the kml file itself? any advice would be helpful.

Please note:
I have the Google Maps Api Javascript V3, I am using MVC4, visual studio 2012, My Kml is stored on a local server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed browser from Google chrome to firefox it all works now