# How to Embed a KML file?

Tags: kml, embeddable-web-maps

I have a KML file (click link to display it in google maps) that works: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx17tEcqrzavQUtzQzVqLTlkTVk/view

I have an embedded google map (works on my blog):

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d678888.4845987434!2d15.089529379165878!3d37.774381418009504!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1490795076461" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

How can I combine these two features so that the kml is displayed on the embedded map? I would like to avoid Java if possible.

Comment: similar question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103939/how-do-i-embed-a-kml-map-using-the-new-google-maps/233990#233990

Comment: similar question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130823/google-map-iframe-kml-not-displaying-correctly

Comment: Seems like java may be necessary: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25317730/add-kml-layer-to-google-maps-embed-api-not-javascript

Comment: Another link suggesting java is needed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591765/canvas-todataurl-for-google-map-ground-overlays

Comment: This might work: more java https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103464/kml-not-overlaying-onto-google-map

Comment: very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598625/how-to-add-google-earth-kml-file-to-html-iframe